# I'm not able to sort the splited strings properly using comparedTo method. What can I do to correct it?

Tags: java, string

This is my code, but I know this is not right. I have written a lot of code for such a simple task.

Sample input is:

> welcome

Sample output is:

> com
>    elc
>    lco
>    ome
>    wel

It should print:

> your first string is 'com'
>   and
>   your last string is 'wel'

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int k1 = k;

        int j = 0;
        int t = str.length();
        String [] s = new String [1000];
        for (int i = t, a = 0; i >= k; i--, a++) {
            s[a] = str.substring(j, k1);
            j++;
            k1++;     
        }

        String[] s1 = new String[j];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < j; i++) {
            s1[i] = s[i];
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < j; y++) {
            for (int z = y + 1; z < j; z++) {
                if(s1[z].compareTo(s1[y]) < 0) {
                    String temp = s1[z];
                    s1[z] = s1[y];
                    s1[y] = temp;
                } 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s1[0]);
        System.out.println(s1[1]);
     }
}
```

Note: I split my strings, but I'm not able to arrange strings in alphabetical order, and feel that I have used a lot of arrays. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to sort the string and print in alpha order? Please clarify your question

Comment: yes, after splitting the string I have to sort in alpha order @andrewdleach

Comment: If they are sorted why is `wel` first and `ome` last?

Comment: Sorry I done a mistake, I want to sort that in alpha order...

Comment: now I make my output properly .....

Comment: your sample output is properly sorted. Thus the issue is not with compareTo, it is with your logic of splitting the string. what char are you trying to split on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- reduce the number of variables,
- use collections (list in this case) instead of Arrays to avoid having to set a size (1000)
- Sort using the framework

  ```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String str = sc.nextLine();
  int k = sc.nextInt();

  List<String> cutStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - k; i++) {
      cutStrings.add(str.substring(i, i + k));
  }

  Collections.sort(cutStrings);
  System.out.println(cutStrings.get(0));
  System.out.println(cutStrings.get(cutStrings.size()-1));
  ```

  }

Comment: Works perfect in small amount of codes, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sort your String[] array by simply using

```
 Arrays.sort(s);
```

This will sort your strings in the default order. If you need any other kind of order you can pass the comparator as a second parameter.

You can get first and last by getting s[0] and s[s.length-1]

Comment: Thanks............... and default order means alpha order???? pls let me know this....

Comment: I think he means ABC order. I think.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick implementation of your requirements. It might not be exactly what you're looking for but it should get you started. :)

So, I used an ArrayList to grab the substrings and the use the Collections library to do the sorting for me. This is just one of the many ways of solving the problem, btw. The input word can vary in size so I felt that a list would be appropriate for this situation.

```
        String s = "welcome";
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 2; i++) {
            String chunk = s.charAt(i) + "" + s.charAt(i + 1) + ""
                    + s.charAt(i + 2);
            words.add(chunk);
            System.out.println(chunk);
        }
        Collections.sort(words);
        System.out.println(words.toString());
```

Feel free to let me know if you have any questions or if I have made a mistake in the code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but pls let me know, how to find my first string and last string in that collection.... one second thanks a lot.....

Comment: Sure. So, "Collections.sort(...)" sorts the substrings in an ascending order. So, by definition, we just need words.get(0) and words.get(words.size()-1) for the first and last substrings respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem of your code is splitting. Sorting will work. If `j` value `1` and `k1` value `3` then `wel` substring is coming. Next loop, (after incrementation of both `j` and `k1` by `1`) `j` value `2` and `k1` value `4` then `elc` substring is coming, etc.

So, instead of

```
    String [] s = new String [1000];
    for (int i = t, a = 0; i >= k; i--, a++) {
        s[a] = str.substring(j, k1);
        j++;
        k1++;     
    }
```

use

```
    int k = sc.nextInt(); 
    String [] s = new String [(str.length()/3)+1] ; 
    for ( int i = 0,a = 0; i<(str.length()-k); i+=k,a++) 
    { 
    s[a] = str.substring(i,(i+k));
    System.out.println(s[a]);
    }
    s[s.length-1]=str.substring((str.length()-k),str.length());//to add remaining values

    Arrays.sort(s);//sorting alphabatically

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
```

`i` value will be incremented by `3`. In the for loop `(i+=k)` where `k=3`.

**Output:**

```
amp
com
e s
ple
wel
```